# Whether to assess normality in a factorial repeated measures ANOVA by looking at distributions within cells?

Tags: anova, normal-distribution, repeated-measures

I'm a little confused about the analysis of normality in a repeated measures ANOVA I'm doing. It's a factorial ANOVA with three rm IVs each of which has only 2 levels. I've read in a few places online and in a book or two that to assess normality in a repeated measures ANOVA, I look at the distributions within each conditions -this would be 8 distributions in my case. However, most of these articles focused on rm ANOVAs in which at least one of the IVs has more than 2 levels.

My confusion is coming from the fact that when carrying out a repeated measures t test (i.e. 1 IV with just 2 levels), you don't care about the distribution for responses in the separate conditions. Rather, you focus on the distribution of the difference scores. In other words, in a repeated measures t-test, we're interested in change.

My questions are:

1. Should I assess normality by looking at the 8 individual distributions associated with each conditions
2. If yes, why is it different for a t-test (which is essentially calculated in the same way)
3. If I shouldn't look at the 8 distributions mentioned above, what should I run my normality analysis on?

Comment: Can you add just what the normality analysis you plan is going to be?

Comment: The assumption is that observations within each group are normally distributed with different means, but the same variance, $\sigma^2$. Therefore, if you subtract off the sample means from each group, you will have one set of $N(0,\sigma^2)$ data, on which you can do a usual check for normality (e.g. qqplot), instead of 8 separate ones.

Comment: John -I would probably be doing a typical enough test like a Shapiro-Wilk. Macro - I don't fully understand what you've written, but I don't have any groups. And since in a it's not an assumption that each condition is normally distributed in an rm t-test, I don't understand why this would be an assumption for a rm factorial ANOVA.

Comment: You call them "conditions", I called the "groups", but we meant the same thing. I think the $t$-test does require normality though, although this assumption is less crucial as the sample size grows. Also, for future reference if you place the '@' symbol before a poster's name, they will be notified when you mention them in a comment :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Macro :) Sorry, I wasn't being pedantic when I said "condition" instead of "group" -it's just that (in my department anyway) group is usually used when we have separate bunches of participants while condition is when we have the sets of scores for the same participants. I know that normality is generally a good thing for a t-test, but the crucial point is that for a repeated measures t-test, it's the normality of the differences scores that counts (as opposed to an independent groups t-test where normality is advised for both the separate groups).

Comment: Just a point of clarity. ANOVA assumes normal *residuals*. The dependent measures themselves need not be normally distributed, although if they are, this guarantees normally distributed residuals. The reverse need not be true, i.e., one can have normally distributed residuals without a normally distributed dependent measure.

Answer (score 3):

There is a reason that we talk about the normality 'assumption' rather than the normality 'condition'.  Whether you are comfortable with the assumption of normality needs to come from knowledge about the science that generated the data, not the data itself.

The tests for normality, when used for justifying the normality assumption, will either give a meaningless answer to a meaningful question (small sample size) or a meaningful answer to a meaningless question (large sample size).

Plots of residuals from an appropriate model (including the repeated measures) can be used along with what you learn by doing your homework about where the data comes from to help you decide if you are comfortable with the normality assumption.  But for deciding if the tests and intervals based on the normal are reasonable, dump the formal tests of normality.